# Commit does not enter the contribution graph

Tags: github

[***I recently made several commits, but they are not being counted, they all follow the patterns they were giving in the past, but recently they are simply not going to the chart anymore, could you help me?***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wutqN.png)

Was there any update that removed this benefit from free users?

https://github.com/Peedrooo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a commit to be counted in the contribution graph, it must have been merged into the default branch in the main repository.  Commits in forks or in branches other than the default branch don't count.

Additionally, if it's in a private repository, you must enable the option for those to appear in your profile.

GitHub provides [documentation on how to troubleshoot this](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile).